# initializing custom container with class/type that has no default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, containers

How can you initialize a container to a class with no default? How can you create the array of pointers required without using new or a method which calls the default constructor of a class?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "MyVector.h"

class NoDefault {
 public:
  //NoDefault():value(0){};
 NoDefault(const int& value) : value(value) {}
  int value;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const NoDefault& noDefault) {
  out << noDefault.value;
  return out;
}

int main() {
  MyVector<int> intVec(10, 99);
  MyVector<std::string> stringVec(5, "hi");
  MyVector<NoDefault> noDefaultVec(4, -3);
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> tempRealVec({{"hi", "bye"}, {"sly", 
"guy", "why"}});
  MyVector<MyVector<std::string> > tempMyVec(tempRealVec);
  MyVector<MyVector<MyVector<std::string> > > vecVecVecStringVec(2, tempMyVec);

  std::cout << "intVec = " << intVec << std::endl;
  std::cout << "stringVec = " << stringVec << std::endl;
  std::cout << "noDefaultVec = " << noDefaultVec << std::endl;
  std::cout << "vecVecVecStringVec = " << vecVecVecStringVec << std::endl;
  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This is the constructor

```
template <typename T>
MyVector<T>::MyVector(const unsigned int& numElements,const T& value):data_(new 
T[numElements]),size_(numElements)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
    {
        if(std::is_same<T,int>::value)
            data_[i]=T(value);
        else if(std::is_same<T,std::string>::value)
            data_[i]=T(value);
        else if(std::is_same<T,MyVector>::value)
            data_[i]=T(value);
        else if(std::is_same<T,NoDefault>::value)
            data_[i]=T(value);
    }
}
```

the error thrown because of the use of new in initializer list is no matching function for call to NoDefault::NoDefault(), even if i create that constructor, which would defeat the purpose. It then prints the vector with the default value not the value given as the second argument in the call to MyVector.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @super How can i work around using new in the initializer list? because new calls the default constructor which is intentionally missing from the no Default class in the main

Comment: You can use [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), or have a look at how `std::vector` implements it's `emplace_back` function.

Comment: @super placement new does not get around new calling the default constructor which does not exist for class NoDefault

Comment: Yes is does. You do `new char[numElements*sizeof(T)]` then construct each `NoDefault` in place by calling the constructor that takes an `int`. This works since `char` can be default constructed when you allocate the memory.

Comment: @super get error cannot convert 'char* to NoDefault*' if i change from new T[numElements] to new char[numElements*sizeof(T)]. get no matching function for the former

Comment: I'm not saying that you can just change `new T[numElements]` to `new char[numElements*sizeof(T)]` and it will magically work. I'm just saying that it can be done with this method. It requires a bit more work though.

Comment: @IsaiahSpearman use `reinterpret_cast<NoDefault*>(new char[n*sizeof(NoDefault)]);`

Comment: @IsaiahSpearman [Here](https://ideone.com/jYRFHL) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use placement `new`.  Placement `new` allows you to construct an object in a specific memory location, so the steps look something like this:

1. Allocate raw memory (`malloc` or `::operator new` both work)
2. Construct your object in this raw memory (`new (ptr) NoDefault{args}`)

This is roughly how regular `new` works (allocates memory via `::operator new`, then uses placement `new` to construct the object).  I'm not sure if stdl containers like `vector` are required to use this method, but I'd be a bit surprised if they didn't.

The big caveat (and it is a big one) is that when using placement `new` you have to manually invoke the destructor (the only time I'm aware of where you intentionally invoke destructors).  After the destructors have been called, you're free to release the allocated memory using the appropriate method (e.g., `free` or `::operator delete`).

More information is available from the [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#memory-pools).